# substring before character in Teradata sql

Tags: sql, substring, teradata, trim

I want to substring before character ignoring the first character (if present).

Data:

AM135678R1  --------------> Solution: AM135678

1837944788D12 --------------> Solution:1837944788

UNZ35789479S --------------> Solution:UNZ35789479

UNV37499888998A2 --------------> Solution:UNV37499888998

Answer (score 1):

All your examples want to remove the last two characters from the string.  Does this do what you want?

```
select left(str, length(str) - 2)
```

As a more general solution, you can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '^[A-Z]*[0-9]+')
```

But this seems like overkill.

Comment: This works, follow up question is there anyway I can also get substring after. For example 1: 1837944788D12 --------------> Solution:D12. Example 2: UNZ35789479S --------------> Solution:S

Comment: @KG11 . . . That might be trickier.  You should ask a new question with multiple examples showing different possible strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521799/substring-after-character-teradata-sql